# What is the correct formula for electric permittivity?

Tags: electrostatics, definition

What is the correct formula for electric [permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity)?

$$K=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$$
$$\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{4\pi K}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a formula for $\epsilon_0$ (vacuum permittivity), you will not find it, because $\epsilon_0$ is a constant.
$$\epsilon_0=8.854187817\times 10^{−12} \frac{F}{m}$$
In other hand, permitivity $\epsilon$ is defined as follows
$$\epsilon=(1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0$$
Where $\chi_e$ is called the electric susceptibility, and is defined with
$$\mathbf{P}=\chi_{e}\epsilon_{0}\mathbf{E}$$
Where $\mathbf{P}$ is the polarization vector.